# Find a so that $f$ is not holomorphic

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f:\Bbb C$ $\rightarrow \Bbb C,$ $f(z)=z^2+a\overline z^2 + 4z\overline z+2z-8\overline z+1+2i$
Find $ a\in \Bbb C$ such that $f$ is not monogenic in any point.

From my understanding I have to find $a$ such that $f \notin \mathcal H(\Bbb C)$.

For $f$ to be holomorphic on $\Bbb C$ we have $\frac {\partial f}{\partial \overline z}(z_0)=0 $ for any $z_0 \in \Bbb C$.

I have computed the following: $\frac {\partial f}{\partial \overline z}(z)=2a\overline z+4z-8$.

But how do I find $ a\in \Bbb C$ from the following: $$2a\overline z+4z-8\not =0 $$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you take $z$ to be purely real, then you get the equation: $2a x + 4x - 8 \neq 0$, yet if one takes $x = \frac{8}{2a +4}$ then the equation does equall zero. Thus we can conclude that no such $a$ exists for all $z \in C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $z = x + iy$. We want to find $a$ such that $2a(x - iy) + 4(x + iy) - 8$ is *never* zero.

Looking separately at the real and imaginary parts, this happens if we never simultaneously have $2ax + 4x - 8 = 0$ and $-2ay + 4y = 0$.

The second equation is easily satisfiable regardless of $a$, by just picking $y = 0$. Can we prevent the first equation from ever holding?

> Yes, by taking $a = -2$, so that the $x$ cancel entirely.